# Angular html-sanitizing blocking the html code by innerhtml

Tags: angular, html-sanitizing

how can I innerHTML this string ( "<img [src]="img(table[0][0])">" )

it gets blocked by html sanitizing.
Also tried to use domsanitizer but it gets rid of src part in img tag.
Can anyone please tell me a way to do it? It's impossible that i need to write all that code by hand while i can use for loops.

html:
'<div [innerHTML] = "str">'

typescript:

```
table: string[][] = [
["b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b2", "b1", "b0"],
["b5", "b5", "b5", "b5", "b5", "b5", "b5", "b5"],
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
["w5", "w5", "w5", "w5", "w5", "w5", "w5", "w5"],
["w0", "w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w2", "w1", "w0"]
];
str = "<img [src] = 'img(table[0][0])' (onClick) = 'click(0,0)'>";
img(str: string)
{
     if(str == "") return empty.png;
     return str+".png";
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create your own sanitize method in component or even in service if you need to share the logic for sanitize 'getSanitizedHtml'. So the src part will not be removed. And after that you can call 'getSanitizedHtml' for example in ngOnInit.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  htmlString: SafeHtml;
  table: string[][] // only example of table, dunno how it looks like inside your code

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.htmlString = this.getSanitizedHtml(this.table[0][0]);
  }

  getSanitizedHtml(imageSrc: string): SafeHtml {
    const html = `<img src="${imageSrc}">`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

and call it inside HTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

Comment: this won't work for me, I need [src] = 'function(param)' because from the function I return the img relative at the vector cell. I need the function so it will automatically change everytime the vector gets an update

Comment: So you need to call the function like getSanitizedHtml from HTML directly ? Or what do you mean ? Can you provide the entire code? I am working based on a short description, and I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.

Comment: yeah sorry, I'll provide a better perspective, everything will be too long, but in short i need this